# Render data in other component when in select tag reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using reactjs, ant design and ant design pro for my project, I have a form like the code below. Option's data is loaded from api. How can I choose that each time I select an option ,the information of that option will appear down to ProDescriptions

props.onInsertObjectFinish(value)} >

```
        <Form.Item  name="TopicId" label="ID chủ đề ">
          <Input id="TopicId"  type="hidden" value={currentRow?.id}/>{currentRow?.id}
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item name='ExhibitId' label="Tên hiện vật ">
          <Select placeholder="Chọn hiện vật muốn thêm" style={{ width: 120 }} onSelect={(value) => props.getvalue(value)}>
            {props.listObj.map((obj: any) => {
              return <Option value={obj.id} >{obj.name}</Option>
            })}
          </Select>
          <ProDescriptions
          />
        </Form.Item>

      </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, create a state

```
const [proDesc, setProDesc] = useState({});
```

create a function

```
 const handleSelectChange = (value) =>{
   props.getvalue(value)
   let index = props.listObj.findIndex(item => item.id == value)
   if(index > -1) setProDesc(props.listObj[index])
 }
```

call function onSelectChange

```
onSelect={(value) => handleSelectChange(value)}
```

and pass this state as prop to ProDescriptions

```
<ProDescriptions proDesc={proDesc}   />
```

now you have a full object of selected option in your ProDescription component, use it how ever you want

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have 2 problems that i met before.
1.when I try to include onSelect's setProDesc function in the Select tag, it informs me that Cannot find name 'obj' because obj is outside the Select tag

2. when I add proDesc = {proDesc} to the ProDescriptions tag it informs me that Type '{proDesc: {}; } 'is not assignable to type' IntrinsicAttributes & DescriptionsProps

I don't understand why I got such an error

Comment: Thank you . function handleSelectChange was running. But how can i render data in ProDescription . I read in doc of ant design pro and they use request and column to show it. I already have column but i don't know how to use proDesc on above code ? . Sorry for many question, I'm newbie in reactjs

Comment: can u plz share the code of ProDescriptions where you want to use proDesc

Comment: i have been add answer below . please help me sold this  problem

Comment: can u plz create a sandbox (with dummy data), so I'll be able to give you a working piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of ProDescription that i can't using proDesc

props.onInsertObjectFinish(value)}>

```
        <Form.Item  name="TopicId" label="ID chủ đề ">
          <Input id="TopicId"  type="hidden" value={currentRow?.id}/>{currentRow?.id}
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item name='ExhibitId' label="Tên hiện vật ">
          <Select
          placeholder="Chọn hiện vật muốn thêm" 
          style={{ width: 120 }} 
          onSelect={(value) => handleSelectChange(value)}
             >
            {props.listObj.map((obj: any) => {
              return <Option key={obj.id} value={obj.id} >{obj.name}</Option>
            })}
          </Select>
          <ProDescriptions
          column={1}
            request={async () => ({
            data: proDesc || {},
          })}
          columns={columns as ProDescriptionsItemProps<TableListItem>[]}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
```

And here is the sample code running of ProDescription

const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState();

```
   <ProDescriptions<TableListItem>
          column={1}
          title={currentRow?.name}
          request={async () => ({
            data: currentRow || {},
          })}
          params={{
            id: currentRow?.name,
          }}
          columns={columns as ProDescriptionsItemProps<TableListItem>[]}
     />
```